# Page navigation using jQuery slideUp() animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I'm trying to create a multi-page navigation using jQuery, where when we change page the current one would suffer a slideUp() and disappear.

Until now I have this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    current = "#div1";

    $("#btn1").click(function() {

        if (current != "#div1") {
            $(current).slideUp("slow");

            current = "#div1";
        }

    });

    $("#btn2").click(function() {

        if (current != "#div2") {
            $(current).slideUp("slow");

            current = "#div2";
        }

    });

    $("#btn3").click(function() {

        if (current != "#div3") {
            $(current).slideUp("slow");

            current = "#div3";
        }

    });

});
```

Running on this: http://jsfiddle.net/93gk3oyg/

I just can't seem to correctly navigate from page 1 to 3, 3 to 2, and so on...

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I am busy drawing up something for you in fiddle, give me a min :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have refactored your code somewhat. I actually do not make any use of the slide-up functionality, everything is handled using CSS animations, which means you will be able to alter those to something else later. Also notice, that this means you don't really need to mess about with z-index.
HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <button class="btn" id="btn1" data-rel-page="div1">Pag1</button>
    <button class="btn" id="btn2" data-rel-page="div2">Pag2</button>
    <button class="btn" id="btn3" data-rel-page="div3">Pag3</button>
    <button class="btn" id="btn4" data-rel-page="div4">Pag4</button>
</div>
<div id="div1" class="fullscreen active">
    <center>HOME</center>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="fullscreen">
    <center>PAGE2</center>
</div>
<div id="div3" class="fullscreen">
    <center>PAGE3</center>
</div>
<div id="div4" class="fullscreen">
    <center>PAGE4</center>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var current = "div1";
    $("[data-rel-page]").bind('click', function (evt) {

        var el = $(evt.currentTarget).attr('data-rel-page');
        if (el === current) return;


        var $el = $("#" + el);
        var $cur = $("#" + current);

        current = el;


        $cur.removeClass('active');
        $el.addClass('active');
    })
});
```

CSS:

```
.fullscreen {
    transition: all 0.4s linear;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fullscreen.active {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93gk3oyg/9/

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

You sometimes notice that the two pages scroll (one up and one down), is there any way to fix this so that the page that you are at when you click the menu stays there and the other scrolls in?

Comment: There are a number of ways you can achieve that, but many of those techniques will be a bit unnatural, where you would have to maintain the z-index values so that the animation doesn't become a bit funky. On approach is to delay the removal of the "active class" like this: http://jsfiddle.net/93gk3oyg/13/ (using js) or http://jsfiddle.net/93gk3oyg/14/ (using transition delay). I think you will find that when you build out those pages the sliding in and out might look better that just sliding over, but that is all a matter of opinion.